# Overloading the ostream operator for a class wrapping stringstream

Tags: c++, stringstream, ostream, istream

I'm currently writing a class to wrap stringstream. My overall goal is to provide a threadsafe << (ostream) for my stringstream. I'm having trouble figuring out the correct syntax of what I'm trying to do. Any help would be most appreciative!

Below you'll find what I've tried. I know this is not the correct syntax, but it is kind of what I'm shooting for. I could of course not overload the << operator and force users to use the AddValue, but that wouldn't be ideal for quick and easy string manipulation while writing the code.

```
class WrappedStringStream

{

public :

   WrappedStringStream() ;

   template<typename T>
   void AddValue( const T & value )
   {

      m_mutex.Lock() ;

      //here I'd like to do something like m_stringstream << value, but of course since
      //I'm overloading operator<< that won't work

      m_mutex.Unlock() ;
   }

   friend std::ostream & operator<<( std::ostream & out, const WrappedStringStream & string )

   {

      string.AddValue( out ) ;
      return out ;   
   }

protected :

   std::stringstream m_stringstream ;

   mutable Mutex m_mutex ; 
}
```

As mentioned above it doesn't compile, which I understand since I'm passing WrappedStringStream as a const parameter and calling AddValue which isn't const - resulting in the discards qualifier error.

Comment: When you do `string.AddValue(out)`, what exactly is this supposed to do?

Comment: @0x499602D2 The AddValue function was defined above with comments of what I'd like it to do.

Comment: Yes but `m_stringstream << value` doesn't make sense when `value` is a `std::ostream`, which is what you passed to `AddValue`.

Comment: Your implementation of the streaming operator doesn't seem to match my expectations. Why would streaming one element to a stream update such element?

Comment: @0x499602D2, I realize it doesn't make sense per-say, but was a guide of what I wanted to do, please don't take the syntax as absolute. I want to overload my classes operator<< function to thread safely add that same stream data into my stringstream member variable since streams, by default are not thread safe.

Comment: This is [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) for sure. Thread safe stream is a strange requirement. If you are doing some multithread logger then there are better ways to solve this issue. If you are doing something else I'm sure there is better solution too.

Comment: Marek there is always a better solution to every problem that each of us has worked one. I believe my question was straight forward - how does one make operator<< threadsafe.  I had mentioned that if a thread safe operator<< was too far fetched then I had already suggested just using my AddValue function and forcing developers to just write CWrappedStringStream wss ; wss.Append( somevalue ) ; I don’t think it’s an unrealistic request to ask for guidance on making the stream operator threadsafe. If you have any suggestions or alternatives, as you’ve mentioned, I’d be interested in them.  Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is the solution

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <mutex>

using namespace std;

class MutexWrapper
{
    private:
        mutex& m_mutex;
    public:
        MutexWrapper(mutex& mtx) : m_mutex(mtx) { mtx.lock () ; };
    ~MutexWrapper() { m_mutex.unlock () ; };
};

class WrappedStringStream
{
    public :
   WrappedStringStream() { };

    template<typename T>
    std::ostream & operator<<(const T& value)
   {
      MutexWrapper wrapper(m_mutex);
      return m_stringstream << value;
   }

void showStream()
{
    cout << m_stringstream.str();
}

protected :
   stringstream m_stringstream;
mutable mutex m_mutex ; 
};

int main()
{
    WrappedStringStream ws;

    ws << "This is a string, " << 5 << 6.78;
    ws.showStream();

    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
This is a string, 56.78
```

======== edit ==========
Originally I was not quiet understand what the questioner's final goal, but just focus on how to fix his syntax issue.It is not a good idea to use << in a multithreading environment. We have a Log class, and in our log class we only have a Log method which takes variable amount of parameters. That will solve the problem.
Still, there is a solution for using << to lock the thread, but really urgly and NOT recommend. Downside is obvious - if you forgot to add the 'LoggingStart' and 'LoggingEnd', you might caught deadlock. 
Also thanks @RemyLebeau, It should return *this instead of m_stringstream.

Please see code below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <mutex>

using namespace std;

class WrappedStringStream
{
    public:
        enum StreamSignals
        {
            LoggingStart,
            LoggingEnd
        };

    WrappedStringStream() { };

    std::ostream & operator<<(const StreamSignals& signal)
    {
        if (signal == LoggingStart)
             m_mutex.lock();
        else if (signal == LoggingEnd)
             m_mutex.unlock();

        return *this;
    }

    template<typename T>
    std::ostream & operator<<(const T& value)
    {
        m_stringstream << value;
        return *this;
    }

    void showStream()
    {
        cout << m_stringstream.str();
    }

protected :
   stringstream m_stringstream;
   mutable mutex m_mutex ; 
};

int main()
{
    WrappedStringStream ws;

    ws << WrappedStringStream::StreamSignals::LoggingStart; 
    ws << "This is a string, " << 5 << 6.78;
    ws << WrappedStringStream::StreamSignals::LoggingEnd;
    ws.showStream();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you so much! I knew I was close to the syntax, but I just wasn't sure. I appreciate the help. I have a similar class to your MutexWrapper which makes mutex protected returns much easier. Again, thank you!

Comment: `std::lock_guard` is a standard version of your `MutexWrapper` class.  This also doesn't remain thread-safe if more than one value is inserted into the stream at a time.

Comment: Do you mean when 1 thread calls ws << "1" << "2" << "3"; and the other 1 calls ws << "a" << "b" << "c"; you may get something like "12abc3" instead of "123abc"? If that is what you mean Yes I think that could be. Oh maybe you are referring to something else?

Comment: How would one protect when inserting more than one element at a time?

Comment: If you are using "<<", you have to protect it around.
mtx.lock();
ws << a << b << "c";
mtx.unlock();
The reason is, your lock is inside the operator.

Comment: The `operator<<` shown won't lock the mutex when chaining multiple values. You would need something more like this instead: `template<typename T> WrappedStringStream& operator<<(const T& value) { MutexWrapper wrapper(m_mutex); m_stringstream << value; return *this; }` Otherwise, you might consider adding public `lock()` and `unlock()` methods to `WrappedStringStream` that you can call before/after chaining, like Tony suggested.

Comment: This doesn't lock the mutex for each element, if you do `ws << "This is a string, " << 5 << 6.78;` it is locked when inserting `"This is a string, "` but not when inserting 5 and 6.78.

Comment: The StreamSignals solution is not safe against exceptions happen in the middle of the << chain.

Comment: @immibis what is your solution?

Comment: As I mentioned when I first asked the question, I could just force the user to call AddValue each time they’re adding something to the string stream. The code may sloppier to write, but would indeed be the most thread safe way to solve the problem and wouldn’t require an override for the operator<<

Comment: You can use variable arguments in your AddValue, so you can add multiple  parameters at a time, just like sprintf. That is my solution in my Log class too. Your AddValue in the question is doing the same thing as << does. It will still not lock when you use sw << "abc" << "def";